# I need to display all post in onepage

Tags: loop

Now its display only 12 item

Here is code. can you please anyone help me

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=faq&post_status=publish&order=DESC&orderby=date=' ) ?>
            <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
                <ul id="myUL" class="margb-40">
              <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Can you append 'posts_per_page=-1' to your query posts?

Comment: Never ever use `qery_posts()` function. See Tunji Ayoola's answer, he is using `wp_query` instead of `query_posts` and this is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Rishabh, why do you prohibit to use `query_posts`?

Comment: @prosti Read this to understand why you should not use query posts http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @prosti I have changed the link of post to better one. Read this

Comment: As you can see @Rishabh, this article is wrong re the `query_posts` it does not consider the `globlal wp_the_query`. Hopefully in few days we will have this changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**WP_Query**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'faq',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul id="myUL" class="margb-40">
    <?php while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>

        //content

    <?php
    endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: Can you remind me why do we need `wp_reset_postdata()` in here? :)

Comment: I always tend to using `wp_reset_postdata()` after every custom call to `WP_Query`. In this scenario, I'm assuming this is on a page template and the global $post variable would be the one generated from the id of the page. So `wp_reset_postdata` restores the `global $post` to the current post in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

you could always add:

```
'posts_per_page'=-1

<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&post_type=faq&post_status=publish&order=DESC&orderby=date=' ) ?>
            <?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
                <ul id="myUL" class="margb-40">
              <?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

if that doesn't work put it in an array:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
    'category_name'  => 'my-category-slug',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'faq',
    'post_status'=> 'publish',
    'order'=> 'DESC',
    'orderby'=> 'date', 
) );
?>
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
<ul id="myUL" class="margb-40">
<?php while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
```

lastly try changing posts_per_page to numberposts.

Comment: check my changes in the answer.

Comment: @rudtek, what do you think about `posts_per_page=-1`, will that work?

Comment: I see.  that might.  eliminate the caret.  that's with a shot too!  thanks for catching that

Comment: @prosti. already done

Comment: you down voted for that?

Comment: @rudtek, Yes, sorry. :) I am not a bad guy thought.

Comment: unfortunately evidence shows otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

WP Dashboard
Settings
Reading
Probably set to display at most 12 posts on blog page.

Comment: Thanks its working. but i don't want display others page like these. is there  any other way we can do this.? pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use `query_posts` you need to use:

`wp_reset_query();` after the block.

```
while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
// do
endwhile;
```